# Unable to run django migrations because of missing contenttypes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm trying to run my Django 1.10 based app migrations on a blank database with:

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

but this fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 224, in handle
    self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias, apps=post_migrate_apps, plan=plan,
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 53, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 191, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/management.py", line 122, in update_contenttypes
    for ct in ContentType.objects.using(using).filter(app_label=app_label)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
```

I get this same error even if I try to run:

```
python manage.py migrate contenttypes
```

Oddly enough, if I run:

```
python manage.py migrate django.contrib.contenttypes
```

then I get the error:

```
CommandError: App 'django.contrib.contenttypes' does not have migrations.
```

So I can't install the model for contenttypes because it has no migrations...but I can't install any other app until the migrations for contenttypes is complete?

What am I doing wrong? Django's [migration docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/) aren't very helpful.

Comment: Why are you passing --run-syncdb flag?

Comment: Run this `python manage.py migrate auth` and then check